# Command line SVG2TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, python, svg

(Apologies if this is too far from topic, but I thought it might be of interest to some here)

I am writing a makefile to take a bunch of SVGs that I have drawn and turn them into TikZ pictures via [SVG2TikZ](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/), but not stand-alone `.tex` files as is the default - I will be `\include`ing these in another file. I have no issues with the makefile. The [documentation](http://wiki.inkscape2tikz.googlecode.com/hg-history/6c437d36ddded127dd06c06a8aa642692f20927a/html/cmdlineguide.html) for command line usage of SVG2TikZ however is sadly not quite up to scratch. The following code works to give a stand-alone file:

```
 python tikz_export.py Tux.svg -o tux.tex
```

(taken from [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/weblog/2012/apr/28/tux-tex-tikz/), using the Tux image linked to at the blog post, and also my own SVGs using appropriate substitutions).

I could conceivably hack the [code](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/source/browse/svg2tikz/extensions/tikz_export.py?r=3b49c159948df17b33d2050f667ef077b6f100ef), but I'd rather not (the relevant bits are near the bottom). Can anyone see a way of calling from the command line and getting a TikZ picture?

Comment: Just to clarify: what you're asking is "is there a way to use `tikz_export.py` to get just a `tikzpicture` environment, without the full document preamble?"

Comment: So basically, when including the converted document, you want to ignore everything up to and including the `\begin{document}` and after the `\end{tikzpicture}`.  I think that the `standalone` class does something similar.

Comment: Either of those would be good. A third alternative would be to get a standalone picture which can then be compiled then included as a PDF image.

Comment: @Jake yes (filler)

Comment: @AndrewStacey yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `svg2tikz --figonly` option generates a `tikzpicture` environment which can be included in a TeX document.