# How do I achieve this in simple TikZ commands?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, conversion

I have a `PStricks` code and made some design in paint and converted to LaTeX code using `Inkscape`. Here is my MWE:

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
 \usepackage[svgnames,pdf]{pstricks}

 \begin{document}
 \psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
 \begin{pspicture}(1122.51968504,793.7007874)
 {
 \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0.0 0.18 0.39}
 \pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
 {
 \newpath
 \moveto(0.21430135,613.28571969)
 \lineto(0.21430135,791.28569953)
 \lineto(564.28569449,791.28569953)
 \lineto(1124.35710236,791.28569953)
 \lineto(1124.35710236,752.28569953)
 \curveto(1124.35710236,726.58745197)(1124.0120315,713.28570709)(1123.34551181,713.28570709)
 \curveto(1122.78901417,713.28570709)(1110.33327874,714.38343307)(1095.66610394,715.72512756)
 \curveto(1047.23973543,720.15496063)(1031.79420472,720.78568819)(971.7463937,720.78568819)
 \curveto(911.02805669,720.78568819)(895.60410709,720.11690079)(854.04661417,715.68215433)
 \curveto(798.76191496,709.78253858)(761.94504567,702.99148346)(705.42568819,688.26837165)
 \curveto(627.87208819,668.06585197)(567.87405354,645.8808189)(430.12792441,586.47367559)
 \curveto(335.62666583,545.71717795)(298.91214614,530.42936693)(255.39842646,513.7168252)
 \curveto(195.55985008,490.73431181)(135.52230803,470.60330079)(75.53238803,453.40648819)
 \curveto(48.22059969,445.57723465)(8.88333846,435.28569449)(6.26950677,435.28569449)
 \lineto(0.21430135,435.28569449)
 \closepath
 }
 }
 \end{pspicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have renewed my answer, please look at it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i assume that this image is some illustration, so the exact coordinates of is not the most important and can be later adjusted by trial. drawing straight lines is simple, for the curved lines i suggest to use `controls` macro:

```
(<coordinate 1>) .. controls + (<control point 1>) 
                         and + (<control point 2>) .. (<coordinate 2>)
```

where sign `+` denote relative position to coordinates.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\definecolor{curcolor}{rgb}{0,0.18,0.39}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[curcolor]
    (0,0) -| (12,-1.2)
    .. controls ++ (-0.5,0.1) and ++ (1,0) .. (10,-1)
    .. controls ++ (-3,0) and ++ (4,1) .. (0,-5) -- cycle;
\path(0,0) rectangle + (12,-8);% if needed
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...interesting... to date you have [444 posts using the phrase "Like this"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A18189+%22like+this%22)...

Comment: @Werner, really?  i newer count ... can you suggest some other (short) phrase?

Comment: @Zarko Don't change. It's perfect!

Comment: @DG', :-), ... but number is fascinating. in time of Werner comment i had this week reputation 666 ... :-(

Comment: @Zarko: My suggestion would be to add some more substance and explain what your code is all about. Why do you use `controls`? What is the syntax of `controls`? Perhaps highlight the reason for `controls` by the same drawing *without* it.

Comment: @Werner, thank you for advice! i don't like to torched english to much :-), so  i rarely make wide description, special when i have filling, that code is simple or self explanatory (about this i'm probably wrong). i will give my best (in exercise writing explanations)

Answer (score 8):

The PSTricks export from Inkscape is crap!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\definecolor{curcolor}{rgb}{0.0,0.18,0.39}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(1122,793)
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]{
 \psline(0,435)(0,791)(1124,791)(1124,713)(1122,713)
 \psbezier(1110,714)(1095,715)(1047,720)(1031,720)%
   (895,720)(854,715)(798,709)(761,702)(705,688)(627,668)(567,645)(430,586)%
   (335,545)(298,530)(255,513)(195,490)(135,470)(75,453)(48,445)(8,435)(0,435)}
\end{pspicture}

\qquad

\begin{pspicture}(1122,793)
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0.0 0.18 0.39}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]{
\psline(0,435)(0,791)(1124,791)(1124,713)(1122,713)
 \pscurve(854,715)(627,668)(430,586)(335,545)(255,513)(135,470)(0,435)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's generally the case from drawing software…

Answer (score 7):

This answer does not try to improve the shape, but explains the translation from `pstricks` to TikZ:

- The dimensions do not need to be specified, in many cases TikZ can calculate the bounding box from the elements on in the picture.
- The color can be defined with the `color` (or `xcolor`) package:

  ```
  \definecolor{curcolor}{rgb}{0, .18, .39}
  ```
- The units settings

  ```
  \psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
  ```

  can be done with options `x` and `y`, `runit` is not used:

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5pt, y=.5pt]
  ```
- A path is filled by `\path[fill=curcolor] ...;` or shorter:

  ```
  \fill[curcolor] ...;
  ```

  Solid fill is the default. A line is not drawn unless `draw` is added.
  This covers:

  ```
  \pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]{
    \newpath
    ...
  }
  ```
- `\moveto(12, 34)` is implicitly done by specifying a coordinate:

  ```
  (12, 34)
  ```
- `\lineto(56, 78)` becomes:

  ```
  -- (56, 78)
  ```
- `\curveto(1, 2)(3, 4)(5, 6)` is specified by `controls` (see Zarko's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409072/16967)).
  The first two points are the control points:

  ```
  .. controls (1, 2) and (3, 4) .. (5, 6)
  ```
- `\closepath`:

  ```
  -- cycle
  ```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{curcolor}{rgb}{0, .18, .39}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5pt, y=.5pt]
  \fill[curcolor]
    (0.21430135,613.28571969)
    -- (0.21430135,791.28569953)
    -- (564.28569449,791.28569953)
    -- (1124.35710236,791.28569953)
    -- (1124.35710236,752.28569953)
    .. controls (1124.35710236,726.58745197) and (1124.0120315,713.28570709)
                .. (1123.34551181,713.28570709)
    .. controls (1122.78901417,713.28570709) and (1110.33327874,714.38343307)
                .. (1095.66610394,715.72512756)
    .. controls (1047.23973543,720.15496063) and (1031.79420472,720.78568819)
                .. (971.7463937,720.78568819)
    .. controls (911.02805669,720.78568819) and (895.60410709,720.11690079)
                .. (854.04661417,715.68215433)
    .. controls (798.76191496,709.78253858) and (761.94504567,702.99148346)
                .. (705.42568819,688.26837165)
    .. controls (627.87208819,668.06585197) and (567.87405354,645.8808189)
                .. (430.12792441,586.47367559)
    .. controls (335.62666583,545.71717795) and (298.91214614,530.42936693)
                .. (255.39842646,513.7168252)
    .. controls (195.55985008,490.73431181) and (135.52230803,470.60330079)
                .. (75.53238803,453.40648819)
    .. controls (48.22059969,445.57723465) and (8.88333846,435.28569449)
                .. (6.26950677,435.28569449)
    -- (0.21430135,435.28569449)
    -- cycle
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution with a `sin` function drawn with `\draw plot`. (You could refine the parameter to match your needs).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\definecolor{curcolor}{rgb}{0,0.18,0.39} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[color=curcolor, fill=curcolor] (-10, 7) -- 
    plot[domain=-10:22, samples=300] (\x,{5*sin(\x/11 r)}) -- (22,7) -- cycle; 
\path (-10, -10) rectangle ++(32,-7); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple correspondence, though not absolutely exact (I think) between the pstricks and Ti*k*Z commands. `(X) \lineto (Y)` translates into `(X) -- (Y)` (inside a `\draw ...` environment) and `(X) \curveto (Y) (Z) ...` becomes `(X) -- plot coordinates {(Y)(Z)...}`. So

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \definecolor{DeepBlue}{rgb}{0,0.18,0.39}
 \fill[DeepBlue,smooth] (0.00214, 6.13286) -- (0.00214, 7.91286) -- 
 (5.64286, 7.91286) -- (11.2436,   7.91286)--  (11.2436, 7.52286) -- (11.2436, 7.26587)--  plot coordinates{(11.2401,   7.13286) (11.2335, 7.13286) (11.2279, 7.13286) (11.1033,   7.14383) (10.9567, 7.15725) (10.4724, 7.20155) (10.3179,   7.20786) (9.71746, 7.20786) (9.11028, 7.20786) (8.95604,   7.20117) (8.54047, 7.15682) (7.98762, 7.09783) (7.61945,   7.02991) (7.05426, 6.88268) (6.27872, 6.68066) (5.67874,   6.45881) (4.30128, 5.86474) (3.35627, 5.45717) (2.98912,   5.30429) (2.55398, 5.13717) (1.9556, 4.90734) (1.35522,   4.70603) (0.75532, 4.53406)}
-- (0.48221, 4.45577) -- (0.08883,   4.35286) -- (0.0627, 4.35286) -- (0.00214, 4.35286);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

produces something which is very close to your screenshot. Other options to smoothen the contour are discussed e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408948/121799).

[image]

But since you seem to have produced the code with inkscape, you may look into the [automatic conversion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170640/121799). I post this because I was unable to get `svg2tikz` installed. (Notice also that I divided your coordinates to make them ti*k*Zable.)

Another, arguably more beautiful way to go is to ask your favorite computer algebra system to find a parametrization of the contour. This yields

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \definecolor{DeepBlue}{rgb}{0,0.18,0.39}
 \draw[domain=0.00214:11.22789,smooth,variable=\x,fill=DeepBlue] plot ({\x}, 
 {-6.9158922189150305 +1.866300006839081*\x - 
 0.10927417962900386*
  (-104.05234359678035 + 
   exp(0.6230737205554076*\x))*
  (1 - 0.14157109964187192*\x + 
   0.005184318196230514*\x^2)}) -- (11.22789,7.91286)--(0.00214, 7.91286) --cycle;  
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, one may play with the curve, i.e. shift and rescale it, and thus make the parametrization prettier.

Answer (score 4):

A code golfing with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\definecolor{x}{rgb}{0,.2,.4}
\begin{document}
\pspicture(\psPiTwo,4)
\pscustom*[linecolor=x,algebraic]{\psplot{0}{TwoPi}{2-cos(x/2)}\psline(!TwoPi 4)(0,4)}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\pscustom*[linecolor=x]{\psplot[algebraic]{0}{TwoPi}{2-cos(x/2)}
  \psline(\psPiTwo,4)(0,4)}`

Answer (score 1):

If you have your desired shape in inkscape you could simply use the extension https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz and directly export from inkscape to `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{c000080}{RGB}{0,0,128}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1.000000]
\path[fill=c000080] 
(0.0,0.0) -- 
(210.0,0.0) .. controls (210.0,0.0) and (210.0,0.0) .. 
(210.0,15.5) .. controls (111.8,15.5) and (112.9,69.3) ..
(0.0,69.6) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]