# Error using svg2tikz: AttributeError: 'TikZPathExporter' object has no attribute 'svg'?

Tags: tikz-pgf, python, svg, command-line

I am trying to turn an .svg file to a LaTeX document. I cloned the [github repo](https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz) for avg2tikz and followed the installation instuctions. After not getting this to work with inkscape I tried to use it with the command line on Windows. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149460/command-line-svg2tikz) question says that the command I need is

```
 python tikz_export.py Tux.svg -o tux.tex
```

After typing this into cmd in the correct directory I get this error:

```
>python tikz_export.py myfile.svg -o myfile.tex

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "filepath", line 1482, in <module>
main_inkscape()
File "filepath", line 1465, in main_inkscape
effect = TikZPathExporter(inkscape_mode=True)
File "filepath", 
line 630, in __init__
self.svg.unittouu = inkex.unittouu
AttributeError: 'TikZPathExporter' object has no attribute 'svg'
```

Is it possible that I need to change `inkscape_mode=True` to `inkscape_mode=False` since I am not using it with inkscape. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please report the issue in the github repository of the tool.

Comment: I don't have a github account... but if there is no simle solution to the problem I will make one.

Comment: But it seems that a similiar issue has already been reported [here](https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz/issues/62). But I don't think the issue has been resolveb